# spring integration | See threads stuck in RUNNABLE for a long time when connecting via sftp inbound adapters

Tags: spring, session, spring-integration

We are using spring integration dynamic sftp flows to ingest sftp files . The flow java config looks like below

```
   from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(cachingSessionFactory, (a, b) -> Long.valueOf(a.lastModified())
            .compareTo(b.lastModified()))//
            .preserveTimestamp(true)//
            .remoteDirectory(job.getRemoteDirectory())//
            .deleteRemoteFiles(job.getDeleteRemoteFiles())//
            .filter(this.compositeRemoteFilter(job))//
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)//
            .preserveTimestamp(true)//
            .maxFetchSize(maxMessagesPerPoll)
            .localFilter(new LocalFileFilter(job))//
            .localDirectory(localDirectory)),
            e -> e.id("testComponent")
                  .autoStartup(false)//
                  .poller(Pollers.cron(job.getPollingFreq(), job.timeZone())//
                        .maxMessagesPerPoll(maxMessagesPerPoll)
                        .receiveTimeout(1000L)    
                        .handle(UploadHandler)
```

The caching session factory is something we get dynamically via using a delegate . Most of it works fine but sometimes after running for days we observe some threads stuck in RUNNABLE . Our assumption was if the jsch session was stuck in any way it should eventually come out as we have timeouts both at the session factory level and at the poller .

The dump for the thread looks something like this

```
java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
com.jcraft.jsch.IO.getByte(IO.java:73)
com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:263)
com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.connect(SftpSession.java:268)
org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession(DefaultSftpSessionFactory.java:390)
custom.adapters.session.LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory.getSession(LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory.java:44)
custom.adapters.session.LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory.getSession(LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory.java:15)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:84)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$1.createForPool(CachingSessionFactory.java:81)
org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.doGetItem(SimplePool.java:195)
org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool.getItem(SimplePool.java:176)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory.getSession(CachingSessionFactory.java:135)
custom.integration.DelegatingLocatorBasedSessionFactory.getSession(DelegatingLocatorBasedSessionFactory.java:80)
custom.DelegatingLocatorBasedSessionFactory.getSession(DelegatingLocatorBasedSessionFactory.java:67)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:432)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:308)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:258)
org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:64)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:45)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:160)org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:360)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$$Lambda$1934/1648215776.call(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$$Lambda$2062/2127922639.run(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$$Lambda$2063/1949167295.run(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274)
org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$$Lambda$1935/1382748208.run(Unknown Source)org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceRunnable.run(TraceRunnable.java:67)
org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please help if we are missing anything here or if there is some configuration we can do on the si side to fix this .
**SI version 5.1.13**

Another heap dump trace of thread

```
"Name","Retained Size","Shallow Size","Level"
"java.lang.Thread [Thread, Stack Local] ""my-taskScheduler-42"" tid=348 [RUNNABLE]","54768","120","1"
"contextClassLoader  org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader [Stack Local]","10324089","80","2"
"<local variable>  com.jcraft.jsch.Session [Stack Local]","21232","256","2"
"threadLocals  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap","15896","24","2"
"<local variable>  java.lang.UNIXProcess$ProcessPipeInputStream [Monitor Used, Stack Local]","8264","40","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource [Stack Local]","4784","96","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter [Stack Local]","2608","176","2"
"<local variable>  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor [Stack Local]","2392","80","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.sftp.inbound.SftpInboundFileSynchronizer [Stack Local]","2168","64","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate [Stack Local]","824","64","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [Stack Local]","744","56","2"
"group  java.lang.ThreadGroup","656","48","2"
"<local variable>  custom.adapters.session.LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory [Stack Local]","512","120","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable [Stack Local]","232","48","2"
"inheritableThreadLocals  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap","104","24","2"
"inheritedAccessControlContext  java.security.AccessControlContext","88","40","2"
"name  java.lang.String ""my-taskScheduler-42""","80","24","2"
"<local variable>  java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask [Stack Local]","72","72","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession [Stack Local]","56","32","2"
"<local variable>  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker [Stack Local]","48","48","2"
"target  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker [Stack Local]","48","48","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor [Stack Local]","40","24","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.JSchSessionWrapper [Stack Local]","40","24","2"
"<local variable>  java.io.FileDescriptor [JNI Local]","32","32","2"
"<local variable>  org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory [Stack Local]","32","32","2"
"pool  org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool [Stack Local]","744","56","3"
"sessionFactory  custom.adapters.session.LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory [Stack Local]","512","120","3"
"jsch  com.jcraft.jsch.JSch","736","32","4"
"proxy  custom.adapters.session.SftpProxyCommand","328","32","4"
"sessionConfig  java.util.Properties size = 2","176","48","4"
"sharedSessionLock  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock","120","24","4"
"host  java.lang.String ""sftp.server""","80","24","4"
"host  java.lang.String ""sftp.server""","80","24","4"
"<class>  custom.adapters.session.LogEnabledSftpSessionFactory org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader","64","64","4"
"password  java.lang.String ""@#@#@#@#""","64","24","4"
"user  java.lang.String ""user""","64","24","4"
"user  java.lang.String ""user""","64","24","4"
"enableDaemonThread  java.lang.Boolean = false","16","16","4"
"serverAliveCountMax  java.lang.Integer = 4  0x00000004","16","16","4"
"serverAliveInterval  java.lang.Integer = 240,000  0x0003A980","16","16","4"
"timeout  java.lang.Integer = 120,000  0x0001D4C0","16","16","4"
"userInfoWrapper  org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory$UserInfoWrapper","16","16","4"
"allowUnknownKeys = boolean false","","1","4"
"isSharedSession = boolean false","","1","4"
"port = int 22  0x00000016","","4","4"
"port = int 22  0x00000016","","4","4"
"<class>  org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader","96","72","3"
"<loader>  org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader [Stack Local]","10324089","80","4"
"<protection domain>  java.security.ProtectionDomain","400","40","4"
"logger  org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Slf4jLocationAwareLog","24","24","4"
"isSharedSessionCapable = boolean true","","1","3"
"sharedSessionEpoch = long 0","","8","3"
"testSession = boolean true","","1","3"
"<local variable>  java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter [Stack Local]","24","24","2"
"<local variable>  java.util.Date [Stack Local] = 2021-01-19 20:30:17.000","24","24","2"
"blockerLock  java.lang.Object","16","16","2"
"daemon = boolean false","","1","2"
"eetop = long 28,082,176  0x0000000001AC8000","","8","2"
"nativeParkEventPointer = long 140,660,716,930,496  0x00007FEE201105C0","","8","2"
"priority = int 5  0x00000005","","4","2"
"single_step = boolean false","","1","2"
"stackSize = long 0","","8","2"
"stillborn = boolean false","","1","2"
"threadLocalRandomProbe = int -884,406,543  0xCB4906F1","","4","2"
"threadLocalRandomSecondarySeed = int 0","","4","2"
"threadLocalRandomSeed = long -7,128,783,728,802,150,278  0x9D1178F7F429C87A","","8","2"
"threadStatus = int 5  0x00000005","","4","2"
"tid = long 348  0x000000000000015C","","8","2"
```

**Proxy custom code for tunneling**

```
public class SftpProxyCommand implements Proxy
{
    
   String command; 
   Process p = null; 
   InputStream in = null; 
   OutputStream out = null; 
   public SftpProxyCommand(String appUser, String privateKeyLocation, String jumpHost)
   {
      this.command = on(" ").join("ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i",
            privateKeyLocation, "-l", appUser, jumpHost, "nc %h %p");
   } 
   public void connect(SocketFactory socket_factory, String host, int port, int timeout) throws Exception
   {

      String _command = command.replace("%h", host);
      _command = _command.replace("%p", new Integer(port).toString());
      p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(_command);
      LOG.debug("Sftp Command : {}", _command);
      in = p.getInputStream();
      out = p.getOutputStream();
   }
 
   public Socket getSocket()
   {
      return null;
   } 
   public InputStream getInputStream()
   {
      return in;
   }
 
   public OutputStream getOutputStream()
   {

      return out;
   }
 
   public void close()
   {
      try
      {
         if (p != null)
         {
            p.getErrorStream().close();
            p.getOutputStream().close();
            p.getInputStream().close();
            p.destroy();
            p = null;
         }
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
         LOG.error("Issue in closing sftp command", e);
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Any chances to try your solution with the latest Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn? If I recall correctly, we did some improvement with caching session factory. On the other hand you can try without caching for time being...

Comment: Ahh ok @ArtemBilan we did upgrade to 5.1.13 and thought https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/8df8028537f06acca3b833f8442f8560e1ab5c8f fixed it . But will try if using simple factory works out for now.

Comment: Can you post the complete thread dump someplace (github gist, pastebin, etc). There is something very peculiar about that thread dump. `FileInputStream` implies connect is trying to read a `File`. It should be a `java.net.Socket$SocketInputStream`. Regardless, (as long as it really is trying to read from a socket), sockets don't have a timeout by default; you can set a timeout on the `DefaultSftpSessionFactory` which should cause this attempt to read to fail after that timeout.

Comment: @GaryRussell adding a heap dump trace for the thread but we have added some timeouts already to the factory and do recycle it after a few hours `CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry> csf = new CachingSessionFactory<LsEntry>(sf);
      csf.setPoolSize(connectionInfo.getPoolSize()); 
      csf.setTestSession(true);      csf.setSessionWaitTimeout(props.getSftp()
            .getSessionWaitTimeout());` the default sf looks like `sf.setServerAliveCountMax(5);  sf.setServerAliveInterval120_000)`

Comment: Also sf.setTimeout(120_000) is also there for socket timeout.

Comment: As I said, this is very strange `java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255)`.

Comment: @GaryRussell one more thing I see are the same number of RUNNABLE **process reaper** threads . Does that ring a bell . Will try to check also not sure if we can put something onthe underlying threadpoolexecutor to recover long stuck threads, or at the poller to exit .. I thought receivetimout shall do it .

Comment: to add context we do use a sftp proxy command to tunnel sftp connecitons

Comment: I just looked at the 3 proxy implementations in JSch and they all return a socket input stream by default - unless you have some funky SocketFactory that returns a `FileInputStream` or a custom proxy. I do see the proxies setting the `SO_TIMEOUT` to the factory's `timeout`, however.

Comment: @GaryRussell nothing fancy we use the defaultsessionFactory with the only custom part being the Proxy (setProxy method as we have a custom tunnel command). Let me check that code though . Also you are right for most threads we get this `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)` when they try to pool and they release unlike the issue ones.

Comment: Also can you point me to those implementation ours is something like above adding to the original post

Comment: I just posted the the proxy command implementation we have for the custom proxy . I meant was what proxy implementations you were looking at to check if we need to change something there .

Comment: They are in the same package as the `Proxy`  class `ProxyHttp`, `ProxySOCKS4` and `ProxySOCKS5`. You are not setting the `soTimeout` in yours. `in = p.getInputStream();` - it's not a socket, you are blocking on STDIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proxy is blocking on STDIN.

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussel for pointing it out , though we have a **jump host proxy** we would need to do ssh tunneling to make it work in our environment unlike these implementations . But let us check our side what we can do about it .